# What is the most efficient way to add a link between two documents in OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

## Background

I'm noticing a significant amount of time in my application is spent adding links between documents using the Java API. I'm trying to reduce this time as much as possible.

## Context

Assume two document classes `Car` and `Engine` with a `LINK` from `Car` to its `Engine`. Also assume that engines are always inserted into the database before any dependent cars, in separate transactions. Given this scenario, what is the most efficient way to link a `Car` to its `Engine` assuming a car only knows its corresponding engine's business key `engineId` which happens to be indexed?

As far as I can see there are 3 approaches using the Java API:

### Client-side: Full Document Linking before `save()`

Naively load the full document of the dependency using the default `fetchplan` of `*:0`:

```
// Return all of the first level fields
val query = "SELECT FROM Engine WHERE engineId = ?";
val engine = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>(query), engineId).get(0);

val car = new ODocument("Car");
...
car.field("engine", engine);
car.save();
```

### Client-side: @rid Linking before `save()`

Instead of loading the full document, only load a reference to document via its `rid`:

```
// Only return the @rid
val query = "SELECT @rid FROM Engine WHERE engineId = ?";
val result = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>(query), engineId).get(0);

val car = new ODocument("Car");
...
car.field("engine", (ODocument) result.field("rid"));
car.save();
```

### Server-side: Update Command after `save()`

Perform the update server-side:

```
val car = new ODocument("Car");
...
car.save();

// Update on server-side
val command = "UPDATE " + car.getIdentity() + " SET engine = (SELECT FROM Engine WHERE engineId = $parent.$current.engineId)";
db.command(new OCommandSQL(command)).execute();
```

Is there a difference between these approaches? Is there a better way?

## Update

After some analysis, it turns out this was an issue due to a missing field in how `Engine` should be looked up. Thus, the index was not being used. After adding the additional field (say `manufacturerId`) things improved significantly. However, I still would be curious as to the recommended method.

Comment: In your code are you using a transactional connection or not tx?

Comment: @AlessandroRota I'm using a `OPartitionedDatabasePool` with no transactions.

Comment: I think that the first two cases are very similar and are faster than the third case.
Can you try with this code ?
Object record=db.getMetadata().getIndexManager().getIndex("Engine.engineId").get(engineId); 
ODocument car = new ODocument("Car");
car.field("engine", record);
car.save();

Comment: @AlessandroRota as it turns out, I was missing another field in my query and thus was not using the index causing things to be quite slow. However, having looked into your suggestion, it appears very similar to the second approach having dug into the implementation. Thanks for your suggestion though!